# python dictionary divide each value in value list by total

Tags: python, dictionary

Thank you for any help. I am new to python. Thanks also for your patience. I am attempting to generate a dictionary that divides each value in a value list by the sum of all values in the value list to get the relative proportion that the value represents of the total for any given key.

There are about 8,000 unique keys each with between 1 and 20 values.

Here is a snippet of code that picks after successfully combining two lists (k, v) into a dictionary.

(Note the last for loop is where the error occurs)

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
    for k, v in values:
        d[k].append(v)
print list(d.items())
```

The print statement generates a list of keys and value list that looks like this ....,('030502060106', [20008611.2, 26323531.9, 18983267.9, 38024346.8]),....

```
for key in d:
    dd[key] = sum(d[key])
print list(dd.items())
```

The print statement generates a list of keys and value list that looks like this (note the value is the sum of the values above)....,('030502060106', [2103339755]),.....

```
for key in d:
    ddd[key] = [d[key]/sum(d[key])]
print list(ddd.items())
```

The error occurs here in this for loop with the following error message TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'float'

How can a new dictionary be generated with a key and value list where each value in the value list is normalized (divided) by the sum of the values?

Modeling it after the first For Loop print statement, it would look like this ,...('030502060106', [0.193619687, 0.254728018, 0.18369762, 0.367954675]),....

Comment: Try casting your list value as a float, like this: float(list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use list comprehension to go through the list of values, divide each one by the sum, and return a list.

```
for key in d:
    ddd[key] = [val/sum(d[key]) for val in d[key]]
print list(ddd.items())
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ddd = defaultdict(list)

for key in d:
    sum = sum(d[key])
    for value in d[key]:
        ddd[key].append(value / sum)
```